# Google Adwords API query the number of conversions per click

Tags: python, sql, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-ads-api

I would like to query the number of conversions per click in a google adwords report using the SOAP API. Unfortuately the following query (Python),

```
# Create report definition.
report = {
  'reportName': 'Last 30 days ADGROUP_PERFORMANCE_REPORT',
  'dateRangeType': 'LAST_30_DAYS',
  'reportType': 'ADGROUP_PERFORMANCE_REPORT',
  'downloadFormat': 'CSV',
  'selector': {
      'fields': ['CampaignId', 'AdGroupId', 'Id', 
                 'Impressions', 'Clicks', 'Cost',
                 'Conv1PerClick',
                 'CampaignName','AdGroupName']
  },
  # Enable to get rows with zero impressions.
  'includeZeroImpressions': 'false'
}
```

results in the following error

```
AdWordsReportError: HTTP code: 400, type: 'ReportDefinitionError.INVALID_FIELD_NAME_FOR_REPORT', trigger: 'Conv1PerClick', field path: ''
```

Google documentation (https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports) seems to indicate that such a report should have a conv1PerClick field (I tryed also removing capitalization of the first letter, similar error occurs ).

Does anybody knows a way to query the ad group statistics about conversions per click?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am understanding you correctly, but the field is called `Conversions`, not `Conv1PerClick`. If you download the report in XML format, then the corresponding field attribute name *used* to be `conv1PerClick`, but this changed in v201402 in line with some changes to the way these metrics are computed:

- http://adwords.blogspot.ch/2014/02/a-new-way-to-count-conversions-in.html
- https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/migration/v201402